# Razor View Engine assignment problem

Tags: razor

I am trying to do some iterative logic in a razor view. I have a very simple do while loop:

```
@do{

  @{parent = parent.Parent}        

}while(parent != null);
```

However the line

```
@{parent = parent.Parent}
```

Causes the following error:

```
[Exception: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `;`:

```
@{parent = parent.Parent;}
```

But because you are already inside the Razor block of the `do` operator it is not necessary to wrap your expression in yet another `@{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confident you could simply do it like this:

```
@do {
  var parent = parent.Parent;
} while (parent != null)
```